# Jquery mousewheel scrolling jerks page

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I have this jquery to mousewheel scroll a div with an id of conentBox. It jerks the page up and down not just the div?  i think i need like a bind or something but i dont know?

```
    $(function() {
$('#contentBox').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
$(this).scrollTop(scrollTop-Math.round(delta * 10));
return false; // prevent default
});     
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reducing the amount you add/subtract from the scrollTop:

```
$(this).scrollTop(scrollTop-Math.round(delta * 2));
```

---

Update: It seems that it does work for me in IE7+... I made [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7n7Ca/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Problem is that in IE it wants to mouse wheel the entire page up and down where i want to mouse a div up and down if my mouse is over the div.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at Mottie's answer and I've found that I get a much cleaner scroll in general if I put first round delta and then do the multiplication. **Like this**

```
$(this).scrollTop(scrollTop-(Math.round(delta) * 2));
```

Is this the case for you all as well?